Double OR question
I faced this sentence in Esperanto DuoLingo course and have doubts about correctness of its translation. "Ĉu vi loĝas en Japanio, aŭ ĉu vi vizitas la landon?" is expected to be translated as "Do you live in Japan, or do you visit the country?". Is it even a valid English sentence?
I would expect from the sentence to be formulated as "Do you live in Japan, or visit the country?". Unfortunately, I can't remember any rule that would make this form correct, so ask for your help, community.

They are both valid, but conversationally most would drop the second “do you” as it is already implied. It does depend a bit on context though. If you were having this conversation in Japan or addressing someone you knew to be in Japan, it would more likely be “Do you live in Japan or are you just visiting?”. (“just” is optional and could be replaced by “only” or omitted altogether).

I agree. I'd expect that unless something non-standard is meant, the best option would be for the 2nd "do" to be replaced by "are" (are you visiting).

Yes, I mean the only time you would ask “do you visit Japan?”, would be if you were asking if they regularly or habitually visited Japan. It would have to be quite a specific set of circumstances to ask “Do you live in Japan or regularly visit?” More likely would be “Have you visited Japan?”, it’s a bit less of an interrogation that way!

It is completely valid.  You can coordinate two questions with "or"  With "yes/no" questions the implication is that if would answer "yes" to one question, then you answer "no" to the other.  Here I suppose you could answer "no" to both (but not "yes" to both).
Since the questions have repeated elements, it is also valid to apply the rules of parallelism and omit "do you" in the second question.  That makes your formulation correct, but it is only correct as a shortened form of the original question.
As a well-known comic example of two coordinated questions, "Is that a pistol in your pocket, or are you just pleased to see me". (attib. to Mae West). As those two sentences aren't parallel, they could not be shortened.
